# How to Insert into.. Value('StringArray[0]', 'StringArray[1]','StringArray[2]','StringArray[3]'....) into database

Tags: sql, jdbc

I tried to read a file and write the data into database.
The file is read to store into the string array, as follows:

```
 String[] result = new String[numberofToken];
```

Then I tried to:

```
Statement stm = conn.createStatement(); 
stm.executeUpdate("insert into login (firstname,lastname,pass, users ) values ('result[0]','result[1]','result[2]','result[3]')");
```

This just stores the "result[0]"..."result[3]" into the database, not the value of result[0]..result[3].

How do I insert the values?

Answer (score 1):

You can use prepared statement and loop the array to set values for your insert query:

```
    PreparedStatment ps = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO login (firstname,lastname,pass, users ) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
    for(int i = 0; i < result.length; i++)
        ps.setString(i, result[i]);
    ps.executeUpdate();
```